# Issues converting nested Plist to NSDictionaries & Arrays

Tags: iphone, nested, nsdictionary, property-list

Given this P-List Dictionary:

[image]

How do I get at the 3rd. Key - "Dinner" - which in itself is also a Dictionary, and parse its values correctly?

Or, should I structure this P-List differently to begin with, so I can get at everything more easily?

Here's what I got, starting by grabbing all the Keys from my 'MenuDictionary' and storing them in an Array:

```
// Load the Property-List file into the Dictionary:
MenuDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:menuPath];

// Get all the Keys from the Dictionary, put 'em into a 'mealTimesArray':
mealTimesArray = [[MenuDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

// For each meal-type KEY, grab all the Values (dishes) in it and store them in a 'mealDishesArray':
for (NSString *mealTime in mealTimesArray) {
    NSArray *mealDishesArray = [MenuDictionary valueForKey:mealTime];

    // Now I can iterate through the 'mealDishesArray' to access each dish at
    // a time, so I can print them out or do whatever else:
    for (NSString *dish in mealDishesArray) {
        NSLog(@"Iterating through 'mealDishesArray' now...");
        NSLog(@"Current 'dish' is: %@", dish);
```

The problem occurs when I get to the "Dinner" key: its a Dictionary, containing 2 Keys with 2 array Values. So how do I load its contents into a Dictionary object? More specifically, what 'init' method should I be using to load the "Dinner" contents into my new Dictionary object?

I tried this - doesn't work:

```
// I put this inside the first fast-enum loop:

if ([mealTime isEqualToString: @"Dinner"]) {
   // init new Dictionary object (declared previously):
   dinnerDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWith ???];
```

I'd like to init it with the contents of the "Dinner" Key, but its not a P-List file obviously, so I can't use

```
   initWithContentsOfFile: pathName
```

I don't understand which of the other init methods will give me access to both the Keys and Values of "Dinner". Because even though "Dinner" is structured as a Dictionary, its currently sitting inside an Array, which doesn't regard it as a Dictionary (I think...)

I'm a little unclear about this obviously.

Or, should I be structuring my P-List differently to begin with so I can get at this nested Dinner dictionary?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think plist structure makes sense, and dealing with the contents conditionally based on class is perfectly okay, too.  I would react to what's in the plist within a reasonable range of expectations, so...

```
// for each meal...
for (NSString *mealTime in mealTimesArray) {
    // we're not sure what kind of meal we have
    id mealInfo = [MenuDictionary valueForKey:mealTime];

    if ([id isKindOfClass:[NSArray self]]) {
        // it's an array? cast as an array and deal with the array
        NSArray *mealDishesArray = (NSArray *)mealInfo;
        [self handleMealArray:mealDishesArray];
    } else if ([id isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary self]]) {
        // it's a dictionary?  that's cool, too. cast as a dictionary and deal with it
        NSDictionary *mealDictionary = (NSDictionary *)mealInfo;
        [self handleMealDictionary:mealDictionary];
    }
}

// you've worked out to handle the array
- (void)handleMealArray:(NSArray *)mealDishesArray {
    for (NSString *dish in mealDishesArray) {
        NSLog(@"Iterating through 'mealDishesArray' now...");
        NSLog(@"Current 'dish' is: %@", dish);
    }
}

// handle the dictionary like a dictionary, realizing that it contains
// arrays, which you've already worked out how to handle
- (void)handleMealDictionary:(NSDictionary *)mealDictionary {
    for (NSString *dishType in [mealDictionary allKeys]) {
        NSArray *mealDishesArray = [mealDictionary valueForKey:dishType];
        [self handleMealArray:mealDishesArray];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing to disagree with.  Did you read after 'What is the solution'?  The first part was describing the problem, which could be clearly observed with NSAssert() (which the poster didn't expect).

Comment: @GoZoner - I read "make them all the same type" and stopped.  My bad.  Will edit out my disagreement, but leave the respect.

Comment: @danh- very interesting approach. I particularly like the idea of Casting an object if/when needed (for some reason I never seem to think of using Casting as a solution to problems - need to read up more on it; curious if there are any restrictions - for example: can _anything_ be cast into anything else?) Also like your breaking it down to different "handle" methods. Efficient and elegant. I'll try this & let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sure.  The cast is less powerful than it might seem.  Think of it more like getting permission from the compiler to treat a certain object a certain way.  But the object at run time won't change.  If you cast a Foo to a Bar and use it as a Bar, even though it's really a Foo, you'll crash.  Best of luck.

Comment: ok, it worked :-) I had to add a line of code to to also store the actual names of the Dinner KEYS (Meat, Vegetarian) but otherwise it was perfect - and it makes sense. Now I need to figure out how to make this PList populate a UITableView controller so as to create drill-down menus :-) (Not to mention be able to update this PList file - perhaps from a web-form, into a MySQL database, through PHP, parsed as JSON, etc. etc. :-)  Good times ahead :-)  Either way, for now, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' is with this line:

```
NSArray *mealDishesArray = [MenuDictionary valueForKey:mealTime];
```

when mealTime is 'Dinner' you are assigning mealDishesArray a value that is an NSDictionary.   Thinking you have an array you then use:

```
for (NSString *dish in mealDishesArray)
```

to iterate over the elements in the array which is not going to give you what you expect for 'Dinner'.  You might consider adding something like:

```
NSAssert ([mailDishesArray isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]], @"Expecting an array");
```

after your assignment to mealDishesArray.

What is the solution?  Your PLIST has a totally different structure between 'Breakfast,' 'Lunch,' and 'Dinner.'  Why is 'Dinner' a NSDictionary and the others are NSArray?  Make them all the same type.  If they can't be, then you *must* conditionalize your code based on:

```
if ([mealTime isEqualToString: @"Dinner"]) {
   NSDictionary *dinnerDictionary = (NSDictionary *) [MenuDictionary valueForKey:mealTime];
   /* ... */ }
```

You don't need to alloc anything or read anything from file; you already have a dictionary for the 'Dinner' data.

Comment: I think your Casting suggestion is very good and I'll try it. However, in terms of the PLIST structure, you said: "make them all the same type" - how can I? We already know Dinner can't be a regular array cause its contents have to be structured as Dictionary (unless you're suggesting multi-dimensional array?) Meanwhile, Bfast and Lunch are clearly not Dictionaries, so how/why should I make them be? Just to match Dinner's structure? I don't follow.

Comment: They don't have to be the same.  I wrote "if they can't be, then you ..."  - so conditionalize on 'Dinner'.